# Can you partially translate your iOS app on the App Store?

Tags: iphone, ios, internationalization, app-store, translation

I am interested in translating my app, but it is expensive. Is it possible to *partially* translate your app and then put that up on the app store? iTunes Connect asks you which languages your app is available in when you upload it. So I have two questions about how it works:

1. If you do not select "French," for example, then it will not say on the app store that your app is available in French. However, if you have some French strings files in your app, will it still work even though your app is not listed as being available in French on the App Store?
2. Also, the only way to get a translated app description on the app store is to select that the app is available in that language. If you say on the app store that your app is available in French, for example, but it is only partially translated and also has a translated app description, then will you get in trouble with the app store submission?

Answer (score 0):

In `Xcode` you localize your xibs and/or add a Localized.strings file. If Localized.strings is localized to English and French, then iTUnes will, after upload of the binary, show the app as being available in the two languages.

The app store description will be in the language you have inserted in `iTunesConnect`. You can for example present English text in the French App store. Or you put a French text as the app description for the English speaking AppStores. I am not aware of rejections due to that.